# die() function does not echo anything in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, die

For example

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```

shows nothing?

I am using PHP 5.4.9

Comment: Are you sure you're not connected?

Comment: Well if it didn't die, it means you connected properly, bro.

Comment: Additionally, please note that the `mysql_*` family of functions is deprecated. Use `PDO` and prepared statements instead: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: congratulations! Connection with DB is OK. If you've some other problems review other part of your code

Comment: Don't use `mysql_`, it's 2013, man !

Comment: I'm with @Darragh. Instead of debugging this, throw it away and [learn how to use PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). There is nothing to be gained by writing an application in an antiquated interface that's being removed from PHP in the near future.

Comment: +1 for PDO.. It's like the future, but now.

Comment: @tadman If I'm not mistaken 5.5 will have it removed completely.

Comment: Easy guys I am just a noob

Comment: I am positive I am not connected to the database, why is not the error message getting echoed?

Comment: You should never use die or show debug information to user. You should show page 500 in case of error (logged error!).

Comment: Atheer, see my answer about error handling

Comment: ok I won't show it to the user but I want to debug the script, why isn't "cannot connect" getting echoed?

Comment: Because you are connected

Comment: Or the code isn't reached.

Comment: Thanks guys, like Dany said it seems I have not closed the connection that I have made earlier :)

Comment: @Daniel In PHP 5.5, which has been released, using `mysql_query` will generate deprecation warnings. It might be removed in PHP 5.6.

Answer (score 6):

`die()` is executed only if the connection to the database fails.

Comment: Additionally this can be simply understood due to the `or` condition. "connect **or** die".

Comment: Or if the `mysql_select_db` function fails.

Comment: @Daniel Yes thats right :)

Answer (score 0):

It shows something only in the case of connection failure.

if you want to show something you can put the connection into a variable and then, put a condition like below:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)
if($conn)
 echo 'Successfully connected';
else
 echo 'Impossible to connect to the host',

$db = mysql_select_db($db_name)
if($db)
 echo 'Database selected';
else
 echo 'Database not exist';
```

Answer (score 0):

With your current code, if you didn't see anything from the die methods, it means that you connected properly to the MySQL server AND the proper database, which is what you wanted, so there is no problem here.

If you take this line, for example :

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
```

There are only two possible outcomes, either the connection attempt is successful, or it will die and print 'cannot connect'. Nothing else can happen.

**The unavoidable**

Please switch from MySQL to MySQLi or PDO. MySQL functions are deprecated, which means they are not supported anymore and as such, they aren't future proof. Here is what typical error handling would look like with [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) :

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

This would display the actual MySQLi error if there is a problem during the connection attempt.